# TikZ snake braces using nodes from diferent 'tikzpicture's

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is it possible to have a brace defined (with the snakes library) using as reference points 2 nodes in 2 different tikzpictures?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
        \draw[draw=black, fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid (4,3) rectangle (0,0);
        \draw[fill=green](1.5,0.5) circle [radius=.3];
        \draw[fill=blue] (0.5, 1.5) circle [radius=.3];
        \draw[fill=purple](1.5, 2.5) circle [radius=.3];

        \node (Bone) at (4,3) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
        \draw[draw=black, fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid (4,3) rectangle (0,0);
        \draw[fill=blue](1.5,0.5) circle [radius=.3];
        \draw[fill=green] (0.5, 1.5) circle [radius=.3];
        \draw[fill=purple](1.5, 2.5) circle [radius=.3];

        \node (Btwo) at (4,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to make a brace that started at 'Bone' and ended at 'Btwo'.

**Remark:** I'm pretty new to TikZ, so even what I'm trying to do here (in my MWE) may have a much simpler way to do it. Any suggestion would be great :)

Comment: Read *16.13 Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Pictures
* on Tikz user guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `remember picture` option on both figures and then insert a third one with `overlay` option to connect them.

Note the use of the `decorations.pathreplacing` library and the changing of node's anchors to adjust the position of the brace. Also you can control the distance of the brace using the option `raise=5pt`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,remember picture]
    \draw[draw=black, fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid (4,3) rectangle (0,0);
    \draw[fill=green](1.5,0.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \draw[fill=blue] (0.5, 1.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \draw[fill=purple](1.5, 2.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \node (Bone) at (4,3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,remember picture]
    \draw[draw=black, fill=black!20!white] (0,0) grid (4,3) rectangle (0,0);
    \draw[fill=blue](1.5,0.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \draw[fill=green] (0.5, 1.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \draw[fill=purple](1.5, 2.5) circle [radius=.3];
    \node (Btwo) at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,decoration={brace,raise=5pt}]
    \draw[decorate] (Bone.east) -- (Btwo.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\draw[decorate] (Bone.center) -- (Btwo.center);` to connect the center of the nodes.